# Missing Dune book

Tags: story-identification

A friend was telling me about an alternative Dune book he's read a few years ago (but now he can't remember the details) that he claims  wasn't fan-fic, it was Frank Herbert.

He says that Paul Atreides walks into the desert to die at the end. I've looked online but (very unskilled in google-fu) I can't find it.

Comment: Paul walks into the desert to die at the end of [Dune Messiah](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/106.Dune_Messiah), the *sequel* to Dune. Could that be what he's describing?

Comment: Nah, I remember suggesting that and he said No, it was deffo at the end of the first book but a different end to the standard story we all  know

Comment: Herbert also wrote an earlier treatment of Dune known as "Spiceworld" (no, not [that one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XbG8d7CM0IQ)). It was published in The Road to Dune along with some short stories. It doesn't end with Paul (Jesse) walking into the desert though.

Comment: Aha! I've just messaged him and he says it was some short stories (He didn't say so at the time) so IMO it was probably The Road to Dune he was thinking of

Comment: None of the short stories in that book bear even the slightest resemblance to what you're describing

Comment: Your friend may have mistaken an omnibus edition for an actual novel.

Comment: @Spencer - interesting theory, but [isfdb](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?2037) doesn't know of a Dune/Dune Messiah omnibus edition.  There are Dune Messiah/Children of Dune editions, and editions containing all three novels, but nothing that has Dune Messiah at the end...

Comment: Maybe he just recalls an unpublished scene/excerpt from Road to Dune? He can't remember

Comment: Another possibility is that he caught the issue of _Galaxy_ with the last serialized excerpt of _Dune: Messiah_. Were all of the stories by Frank Herbert?

Comment: He can't remember. IMO he's got things confused but he won't admit he's wrong (79 years old and mega stubborn!)